# Struct array in struct

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to declare `struct` array field in another `struct`?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct A
{
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct B
{
    public fixed A FieldA[123];
}
```

Visual Studio tells that `FieldA` can only be an array of any simple type not a `struct`. Is there any solution/workaround here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to declare struct array field in another struct?

Yes, but there are restrictions if you want to make it a fixed-size buffer. From section 18.7.1 of the C# 4 spec:

> The buffer element type of a fixed size buffer declaration specifies the element type of the buffer(s) introduced by the declaration. The buffer element type must be one of the predefined types `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `float`, `double`, or `bool`.

I don't know of any alternatives to emulate fixed sized buffers of arbitrary structs.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the second struct in this way :

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct B
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=123)]
    public fixed A[] FieldA;
}
```